# heartbeat stops after reviving primary node

Tags: cluster, heartbeat

I followed [these steps](http://www.howtoforge.com/high_availability_heartbeat_centos) correctly, everything worked well before I have revived heartbeat on node01 "at the last steps of the tutorial"
when I hit `/etc/init.d/heartbeat start` it started correctly but the webpage wouldn't open, in other words httpd service haven't been started by heartbeat (which I guess the reason is that the node02 still the primary node it hasn't returned to secondary yet)

so I searched for the STONITH but i didn't find anything that helps.
this is the ha.cf file:

```
logfile /var/log/ha-log
logfacility local0
keepalive 2
deadtime 30
initdead 120
bcast eth0
udpport 694
auto_failback on
node node01
node node02
```

haresources file:

```
node01 192.168.1.82 httpd
```

authkeys file:

```
auth 2
2 sha1 test-ha
```